# Error in 1: subscript out of bounds when web-scraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am webscraping data from 'https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Situation/daily-firesituation.html'

```
library('rvest')
url_Manitoba <- 'https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Situation/daily-firesituation.html'
webpage_Manitoba <- read_html(url_Manitoba)

population <- url %>%
xml2::read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//*        
[@id="Fire_Program_Template_Stuff"]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td') %>%
html_table()
population <- population[[1]]
```

Error in population[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure your xpath statement is correct.  I find it easier to use the CSS tags to pull the requested information.

In case, I am pulling all of the table nodes, I believe you are interested in the second table.

```
library('rvest')
url_Manitoba <- 'https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Situation/daily-firesituation.html'
webpage_Manitoba <- read_html(url_Manitoba)

population <- webpage_Manitoba %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
population[[2]]
```

From here population[[2]] is a data frame with the contents of the main table. It is just a matter of querying the proper row and/or column for the specific information.